# MYSQL Query Remove Duplicates by column value if already in a group

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a table with "inventory" and a table that contains "requests" for items in inventory.

I need a query that results in a list indicating what items to pull from inventory and which user get's the inventory.

Often, there is not enough in inventory to accommodate the requests for items in inventory, so users with the lowest requests.id should be accommodated first.

```
create table inventory (id int, product_type varchar(56), sku varchar(56));
insert into inventory values
(1,     'bike', 'b1'),
(2,     'bike', 'b2'),
(3,     'scooter', 's1'),
(4,     'scooter', 's2'),
(5,     'unicycle', 'u1');

create table requests (id int, user_id int, product_type varchar(56));
insert into requests values
(1,   1,   'bike'),
(2,   2,  'bike'),
(3,   2,  'scooter'),
(4,   3,   'bike'),
(5,   3,   'scooter');
```

Using this generic data as an example, the desired output would be this:

| user_id | product_type | sku |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | bike | b1 |
| 2 | bike | b2 |
| 2 | scooter | s1 |
| 3 | scooter | s2 |

Note that even though user_id 3 requested a bike, they don't get one because there are only two in inventory.

I started this sql fiddle

https://dbfiddle.uk/j7FeFr6z

Comment: the fiddle has less rows as the sample data in your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER` to join the two tables, so that every one gets his vehicle as long as there are the product tapes in the inventory

```
SELECT user_id,i.product_type,i.sku
  FROM
(SELECT product_type, sku, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY product_type ORDER BY id) rn
FROM inventory) i JOIN
(SELECT product_type,user_id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY product_type ORDER BY id) rn  FROM requests) r
  ON i.rn = r.rn  AND i.product_type = r.product_type
  ORDER BY user_id;
```

| user_id | product_type | sku |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | bike | b1 |
| 2 | scooter | s1 |
| 2 | bike | b2 |
| 3 | scooter | s2 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/fPWRg8ih)